# How to read value of accumulators in worker task in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, accumulator, shared-variable

As per the documentation of accumulators in spark:

> Note that tasks on worker nodes cannot access the accumulator’s value()—from the point of view of these tasks, accumulators are write-only variables. This allows accu‐ mulators to be implemented efficiently, without having to communicate every update.

Accumulators are write-only variable for worker nodes.

Is there any way we can read the accumulators value in worker node and use its value for some business logic?

Comment: from what place do you want to read it? outside jvm or from some function inside spark app

Comment: It is inside the same spark app.

Comment: don't think it's possible at all, because braking "write-only" restriction would mean that you need "shuffle" on each read access to acc because there is no guaranty that variable that you are trying to read on your node contain last value. The accumulator is spread across the nodes, so the result value can be calculated only AFTER all tasks writing to it stopped writing and the value will be distributed across all noted interested in reading it.